# How to ensure the numeric value is always positive in Optimization Python?

Tags: optimization, python, quadratic-programming

I am currently performing optimization onto a quadratic function by manually coding the algorithm:

$$\min f = x^T v x - r^T x\\
\text{subject to } x \geq 0\, .$$

Here, optimizing the function without the constraint above is not a problem at all. However, if I want to add this inequality constraint, I do not know how can I implement it in Python. I have seen Scipy Optimization Package uses `np.clip` to clamp the array within the bound, but it is forcing negative values to 0, thus somehow affecting the answer to finding the minimum point.

I wish to know if there is any other method to naturally ensure the array of numeric values always stays positive in every iteration?

Comment: I have typed your equations using MathJax, please check that it is correct.

Comment: Is $v$ a positive definite matrix? Does $x \geq 0$ mean that all components of $x$ are nonnegative?

Comment: Hi @nicoguaro, thanks for the help! Yes the equation is correct, and yes, $v$ must be at least positive semidefinite and all the $x > 0$ in every iteration

Answer (score 4):

Consider a variable transform. Assuming you care about the individual entries of $x$ and not something like its determinant, you can transform the $x_i$ such that the new variable $y_i$ is not bounded but the $x_i$ are. Logarithms are helpful for this;

$y_i=log(x_i)$

Then you can adjust your objective function to include the transform back to $x$ and optimize for $y=(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks @Root of All Things for this suggestion, but I was wondering if transforming it to logarithms will cause any deviation in the minimum point of the objective function?

Comment: It shouldn't, in my experience. Note that this transformation requires including the reverse transformation in the objective function: $minf=(e^y)^T v(e^y)−r^T(e^y)$, where this exponential isn't a matrix exponential but the element-wise exponential. This gives the minimum point in the y-space, but that's just one transform away from the minimum point in the x-space.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I will try this transformation to see its efficiency. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Introduce an unconstrained vector $w$ and use it to construct
an $x$ vector such that $x>0$ using an *elementwise* exponential function
$$\eqalign{
x &= {e^w} \qiq dx = x\odot dw \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient of the function with respect to $w$
and follow the usual prescription of setting it to zero
and solving for the optimal vector.
$$\eqalign{
f &= V:xx^T - r:x \\
df &= \LR{2Vx - r}:dx \\
 &= \LR{2Vx - r}:\LR{x\odot dw} \\
 &= x\odot \LR{2Vx - r}:dw \\
\grad{f}{w} &= x\odot \LR{2Vx - r} \;\doteq\; 0 \\
 r &= 2Vx \\
x &= \frac 12V^+r \\
}$$
In the above, $V^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse, $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product, and $(:)$ denotes the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:\LR{B\odot C}
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}\LR{B_{ij}C_{ij}} \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \LR{A_{ij}B_{ij}}C_{ij} \\
 &= \LR{A\odot B}:C \\
}$$
Substitute this back into the original function
$$\eqalign{
f &= x^TVx - r^Tx \\
f &= \frac 14\LR{r^TV^+VV^+r} - r^TV^+r \\
 &= \frac 14\LR{r^TV^+r}- \LR{r^TV^+r} \\
 &= -\frac 34\LR{r^TV^+r} \\
}$$